# How to create a PyArray to feed into method

Tags: rust, pyo3, rust-ndarray

I have a method `foo` with the following signature:

```
pub fn foo(data: PyReadonlyArrayDyn<f64>) {
    ...
}
```

In my test I'm trying to create a test array to feed into `foo`

```
pyo3::Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let vec = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    py_array = PyArray::from_vec(py, vec);
    readonly = py_array.readonly();
    foo(readonly);
}
```

Unfortunately, rust tells me:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `PyReadonlyArray<'_, f64, Dim<IxDynImpl>>`
   found struct `PyReadonlyArray<'_, {float}, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`
```

Apparently, I'm running into a problem regarding dimensionality. How do I have to create the `PyReadonlyArray` to be able to feed it into `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`PyArray::to_dyn()`](https://docs.rs/numpy/latest/numpy/array/struct.PyArray.html#method.to_dyn):

```rust
pyo3::Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let vec = vec![1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    py_array = PyArray::from_vec(py, vec);
    readonly = py_array.to_dyn().readonly();
    foo(readonly);
}
```